# Why does maven give me this Scala error doing clean install

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea, build, package

I can't seem to find why scala packages are being "thought of" by maven as a member of `package org.apache.kafka.streams.scala`. I usually use sbt but I have to use maven on this one.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_172.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=/Users/jcena1/IdeaProjects/datapipe-scala-merge-transform "-Dmaven.home=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/bin/m2.conf" "-javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=65172:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2018.2.1 install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for io.confluent:Jointransform:jar:4.1.1
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar -> duplicate declaration of version ${scala.version} @ io.confluent:Jointransform:[unknown-version], /Users/jcena1/IdeaProjects/datapipe-scala-merge-transform/pom.xml, line 259, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Detecting the operating system and CPU architecture
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] os.detected.name: osx
[INFO] os.detected.arch: x86_64
[INFO] os.detected.version: 10.13
[INFO] os.detected.version.major: 10
[INFO] os.detected.version.minor: 13
[INFO] os.detected.classifier: osx-x86_64
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Jointransform 4.1.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.17:check (validate) @ Jointransform ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M1:enforce (enforce-versions) @ Jointransform ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.10:add-source (add-source) @ Jointransform ---
[INFO] Source directory: /Users/jcena1/IdeaProjects/datapipe-scala-merge-transform/src/main/scala added.
[INFO] Source directory: /Users/jcena1/IdeaProjects/datapipe-scala-merge-transform/target/generated-sources added.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- avro-maven-plugin:1.8.2:schema (default) @ Jointransform ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.2:resources (default-resources) @ Jointransform ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 28 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) @ Jointransform ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 11 source files to /Users/jcena1/IdeaProjects/datapipe-scala-merge-transform/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- scala-maven-plugin:3.2.1:compile (default) @ Jointransform ---
[INFO] /Users/jcena1/IdeaProjects/datapipe-scala-merge-transform/src/main/scala:-1: info: compiling
[INFO] /Users/jcena1/IdeaProjects/datapipe-scala-merge-transform/target/generated-sources:-1: info: compiling
[INFO] /Users/jcena1/IdeaProjects/datapipe-scala-merge-transform/target/generated-sources/annotations:-1: info: compiling
[INFO] Compiling 16 source files to /Users/jcena1/IdeaProjects/datapipe-scala-merge-transform/target/classes at 1536749088682
[ERROR] /Users/jcena1/IdeaProjects/datapipe-scala-merge-transform/src/main/scala/acme/Filtertransform.scala:10: error: object language is not a member of package org.apache.kafka.streams.scala
[ERROR] import scala.language.implicitConversions
[ERROR]              ^
[ERROR] /Users/jcena1/IdeaProjects/datapipe-scala-merge-transform/src/main/scala/acme/Filtertransform.scala:14: error: object collection is not a member of package org.apache.kafka.streams.scala
[ERROR] import scala.collection.mutable
[ERROR]              ^
[ERROR] /Users/jcena1/IdeaProjects/datapipe-scala-merge-transform/src/main/scala/acme/Filtertransform.scala:75: error: Symbol 'type org.apache.kafka.streams.Consumed' is missing from the classpath.
[ERROR] This symbol is required by 'value com.lightbend.kafka.scala.streams.StreamsBuilderS.consumed'.
[ERROR] Make sure that type Consumed is in your classpath and check for conflicting dependencies with `-Ylog-classpath`.
[ERROR] A full rebuild may help if 'StreamsBuilderS.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of org.apache.kafka.streams.
[ERROR]         val stream: KStreamS[String, Array[Byte]] = builder.stream(inputTopic)
[ERROR]                                                     ^
[ERROR] /Users/jcena1/IdeaProjects/datapipe-scala-merge-transform/src/main/scala/acme/GroupBytransform.scala:12: error: object collection is not a member of package org.apache.kafka.streams.scala
[ERROR] import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
[ERROR]              ^
[ERROR] /Users/jcena1/IdeaProjects/datapipe-scala-merge-transform/src/main/scala/acme/GroupBytransform.scala:11: error: object language is not a member of package org.apache.kafka.streams.scala
[ERROR] import scala.language.implicitConversions
[ERROR]              ^
[ERROR] /Users/jcena1/IdeaProjects/datapipe-scala-merge-transform/src/main/scala/acme/GroupBytransform.scala:20: error: object collection is not a member of package org.apache.kafka.streams.scala
[ERROR] import scala.collection.mutable
[ERROR]              ^
[ERROR] /Users/jcena1/IdeaProjects/datapipe-scala-merge-transform/src/main/scala/acme/GroupBytransform.scala:21: error: object collection is not a member of package org.apache.kafka.streams.scala
[ERROR] import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
[ERROR]              ^
[ERROR] /Users/jcena1/IdeaProjects/datapipe-scala-merge-transform/src/main/scala/acme/GroupBytransform.scala:39: error: Symbol 'type org.apache.kafka.streams.Consumed' is missing from the classpath.
[ERROR] This symbol is required by 'method com.lightbend.kafka.scala.streams.ImplicitConversions.consumedFromSerde'.
[ERROR] Make sure that type Consumed is in your classpath and check for conflicting dependencies with `-Ylog-classpath`.
[ERROR] A full rebuild may help if 'ImplicitConversions.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of org.apache.kafka.streams.
[ERROR]           (out:+ s)
[ERROR]                  ^
[ERROR] /Users/jcena1/IdeaProjects/datapipe-scala-merge-transform/src/main/scala/acme/GroupBytransform.scala:57: error: value asScala is not a member of java.util.List[String]
[ERROR] possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value asScala'?
[ERROR]         .asScala
[ERROR]          ^
[ERROR] /Users/jcena1/IdeaProjects/datapipe-scala-merge-transform/src/main/scala/acme/GroupBytransform.scala:147: error: not found: value Consumed
[ERROR]       implicit val c = Consumed.`with`(Serdes.String(), Serdes.ByteArray())
[ERROR]                        ^
[ERROR] /Users/jcena1/IdeaProjects/datapipe-scala-merge-transform/src/main/scala/acme/GroupBytransform.scala:149: error: polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type;
[ERROR]  found   : [K, V]org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KTable[K,V]
[ERROR]  required: org.apache.kafka.streams.scala.kstream.KTable[String,Array[Byte]]
[ERROR]       val table: KTable[String, Array[Byte]] = builder.table(inputTopic)
[ERROR]                                                             ^
[ERROR] /Users/jcena1/IdeaProjects/datapipe-scala-merge-transform/src/main/scala/acme/GroupBytransform.scala:156: error: not found: value Serialized
[ERROR]       implicit val sb = Serialized.`with`(Serdes.String(), Serdes.ByteArray())
[ERROR]                         ^
[ERROR] /Users/jcena1/IdeaProjects/datapipe-scala-merge-transform/src/main/scala/acme/GroupBytransform.scala:157: error: not found: value Serialized
[ERROR]       implicit val ss = Serialized.`with`(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String())
[ERROR]                         ^
[ERROR] /Users/jcena1/IdeaProjects/datapipe-scala-merge-transform/src/main/scala/acme/GroupBytransform.scala:158: error: not found: value Produced
[ERROR]       implicit val p = Produced.`with`(Serdes.String(),Serdes.String())
[ERROR]                        ^
[ERROR] /Users/jcena1/IdeaProjects/datapipe-scala-merge-transform/src/main/scala/acme/GroupBytransform.scala:241: error: value asScala is not a member of java.util.List[String]
[ERROR] possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value asScala'?
[ERROR]                 .asScala
[ERROR]                  ^
[ERROR] /Users/jcena1/IdeaProjects/datapipe-scala-merge-transform/src/main/scala/acme/GroupBytransform.scala:245: error: value asScala is not a member of java.util.List[String]
[ERROR]           val newValue = getValFromJSONMessage(lv, aggregateColumnList.asScala.toList.head)
[ERROR]                                                                        ^
[ERROR] /Users/jcena1/IdeaProjects/datapipe-scala-merge-transform/src/main/scala/acme/GroupBytransform.scala:232: error: diverging implicit expansion for type org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Serialized[KR,VR]
[ERROR] starting with method consumedFromSerde in object ImplicitConversions
[ERROR]       val groupedK = table.groupBy{ (key: String, value: Array[Byte]) =>
[ERROR]                                   ^
[ERROR] /Users/jcena1/IdeaProjects/datapipe-scala-merge-transform/src/main/scala/acme/GroupBytransform.scala:252: error: not found: type Aggregator
[ERROR]         val newAggregator: Aggregator[String, Array[Byte], Array[Byte]] = new Aggregator[String, Array[Byte], Array[Byte]] {
[ERROR]                            ^
[ERROR] /Users/jcena1/IdeaProjects/datapipe-scala-merge-transform/src/main/scala/acme/GroupBytransform.scala:252: error: not found: type Aggregator
[ERROR]         val newAggregator: Aggregator[String, Array[Byte], Array[Byte]] = new Aggregator[String, Array[Byte], Array[Byte]] {
[ERROR]                                                                               ^
[ERROR] /Users/jcena1/IdeaProjects/datapipe-scala-merge-transform/src/main/scala/acme/Jointransform.scala:10: error: object language is not a member of package org.apache.kafka.streams.scala
[ERROR] import scala.language.implicitConversions
[ERROR]              ^
[ERROR] /Users/jcena1/IdeaProjects/datapipe-scala-merge-transform/src/main/scala/acme/Jointransform.scala:11: error: object collection is not a member of package org.apache.kafka.streams.scala
[ERROR] import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
[ERROR]              ^
[ERROR] /Users/jcena1/IdeaProjects/datapipe-scala-merge-transform/src/main/scala/acme/Jointransform.scala:18: error: object collection is not a member of package org.apache.kafka.streams.scala
[ERROR] import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
[ERROR]              ^
[ERROR] /Users/jcena1/IdeaProjects/datapipe-scala-merge-transform/src/main/scala/acme/Jointransform.scala:37: error: not found: type ListBuffer
[ERROR]                 val lst = new ListBuffer[String]
[ERROR]                               ^
[ERROR] /Users/jcena1/IdeaProjects/datapipe-scala-merge-transform/src/main/scala/acme/Jointransform.scala:84: error: value asScala is not a member of java.util.List[String]
[ERROR]  Note: implicit value j is not applicable here because it comes after the application point and it lacks an explicit result type
[ERROR]         val leftRekeyColumnList = if(rekeyLeftNeeded) joinStep.getStringList("joinOn.leftFields").asScala.toList else List.empty
[ERROR]                                                                                                   ^
[ERROR] /Users/jcena1/IdeaProjects/datapipe-scala-merge-transform/src/main/scala/acme/Jointransform.scala:85: error: value asScala is not a member of java.util.List[String]
[ERROR]  Note: implicit value j is not applicable here because it comes after the application point and it lacks an explicit result type
[ERROR]         val rightRekeyColumnList = if(rekeyRightNeeded) joinStep.getStringList("joinOn.rightFields").asScala.toList else List.empty
[ERROR]                                                                                                      ^
[ERROR] /Users/jcena1/IdeaProjects/datapipe-scala-merge-transform/src/main/scala/acme/Jointransform.scala:96: error: value asScala is not a member of java.util.List[String]
[ERROR]  Note: implicit value j is not applicable here because it comes after the application point and it lacks an explicit result type
[ERROR]             if(!JoinUtils.validateFilterExpression(filterExpression.asScala.toList)) {
[ERROR]                                                                     ^
[ERROR] /Users/jcena1/IdeaProjects/datapipe-scala-merge-transform/src/main/scala/acme/Jointransform.scala:147: error: value asScala is not a member of java.util.List[String]
[ERROR]                                     JoinUtils.joinValues(lv, rv, node, outputFields.asScala.toList)
[ERROR]                                                                                     ^
[ERROR] /Users/jcena1/IdeaProjects/datapipe-scala-merge-transform/src/main/scala/acme/Jointransform.scala:157: error: value asScala is not a member of java.util.List[String]
[ERROR]                 val filterPredicate = JoinUtils.buildPostJoinPredicate(filterExpression.asScala.toList, lv)
[ERROR]                                                                                         ^
[ERROR] /Users/jcena1/IdeaProjects/datapipe-scala-merge-transform/src/main/scala/acme/Jointransform.scala:165: error: value asScala is not a member of java.util.List[String]
[ERROR]                 val ba: Array[Byte] = JoinUtils.removeEntryFromJsonNode(extraFields.asScala.toList, value)
[ERROR]                                                                                     ^
[ERROR] 29 errors found
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 10.937 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-09-12T06:44:53-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 35M/376M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.1:compile (default) on project Jointransform: wrap: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to prefix `_root_` to all the Scala core packages like for example

```
import _root_.scala.collection.JavaConverters._
```